# Can a PHP script run on my server the whole time?

Tags: php

I am pretty new to PHP but I want to crate a website uptime checker which should email me whenever my websites are down.

This means that the script should run non stop. Can this be done in PHP? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You want to run a script at a set interval instead. Cron is what you want.

Here's a tutorial to get started. http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/managing-cron-jobs-with-php-2/

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [`cron task`](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/07/php-cron-job/) to schedule your script running at regular intervals. Or if you are hosting on Windows use the Windows Scheduler.

Comment: this pretty much answers my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Normally there's an [execution time](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) limit that will stop scripts from running longer than a specified time. A better solution would be to set up a [cron job](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) that executes the script periodically.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by a cron job (a script to check your website) and make it run at regular intervals.